# show list according to the letter clicked in jade data retrieve from mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, mean-stack

I sent my data to pug file as `data.brand_name` to show all brand

Now i want to show the brands according to alphabets.

[image: click to see the images]

I want when i click on a letter `'a'` then it only show a list which has starting letter `'a'`

I don't got how to do this,please help me.

**EDIT 1**

my pug file for aplhabet is like this

```
 div.row
                            div.drug_alphabets.pull-left
                                span.center
                                    ul
                                        li
                                            a.btn2.hoverable(href='#') A
                                        li
                                            a.btn2.hoverable(href='#') B
                                        li
                                            a.btn2.hoverable(href='#') C
                                        li
                                            a.btn2.hoverable(href='#') D
```

I am using this code to display brands

```
   for each brand in data   
      h4 brand- #{brand.brand_name}
```

i get brands like

```
brand - a
brand - b
brand - c
```

Comment: Can you please share your  **.pug** file and  `brand_name` data examle ?

Comment: @agit  please see upward

Comment: did the following answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **jQuery** to achive your goal. But first of all you need to add a additional `class` for parent `div` of brand names (in this case I used `.brands`) and add an `attribute` for **h4** element to store brand names.

```
.brands
    for each brand in data   
        h4(name=brand.brand_name) brand- #{brand.brand_name}
```

Then include **jQuery** to your page and use following script after page load.

```
$(".drug_alphabets a").on("click", function() {

    var clickedLetter = $(this).text()

    $(".brands h4").each(function() {
        var brandName = $(this).attr("name")
        if (brandName && brandName.toLowerCase()[0] == clickedLetter.toLowerCase()) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

})
```

Here is working snippet : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZavPNo

Comment: sorry, i don't get it.i tried a lot.but when i clicked on any alphabets ,its shows nothing.

Comment: @Rupeshyadav sorry, I update the jade code above, can try again ?

Comment: but what is meant by  `if (brandName && brandName.toLowerCase()[0] == clickedLetter.toLowerCase())`.  why we use this?

Comment: @Rupeshyadav because `brandName` value can be start with uppercase or can be empty ( if you sure `brandName` will not be empty you can use `if (brandName.toLowerCase()[0] == clickedLetter.toLowerCase())` ).

Comment: thnx for answering my question.