# show list according to letter clicked in pug from mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, mean-stack

Previous question: [show list according to the letter clicked in jade data retrieve from mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381397/show-list-according-to-the-letter-clicked-in-jade-data-retrieve-from-mongodb)

If I click on any alphabets it shows the brand accordingly.

The problem occurs when user clicks on `other brand` option where it has to show brands that don't start with alphabets `A-Z`.

I don't know how to do that.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZavPNo still work for demo purposes?

Comment: yes still works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed my previous answer, see: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooqmNX

I added show all and other options to list, bu this items have additional `attribute` named `type` to use.

```
var type = $(this).attr("type")
if (type) {
    if (type == "all") {
        $(".brands h4").show();//show all
    } else if (type == "other") {
        $(".brands h4").hide();//hide all
        $(".brands h4").each(function() {
            var brandName = $(this).attr("name")
            if (!brandName.toLowerCase()[0].match(/[a-z]/i))//if name not starts with letter
                $(this).show();
        });
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: thnx again sir.